# Reference request: English version of "Über eine Ungleichung von Cheeger "

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Is there English version of Über eine Ungleichung von Cheeger? I found a German edition, but I can't read German.

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=-Y8DCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) article? It might be relevant.